# Why I obtain this error when I create a table on MariaDB? "Could not getColumn for MyMariaDB: Unknown system variable 'OPTION'"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, rdbms

I have installed **MariaDB** and I am finding some dificulties trying to create this simple table:

```
CREATE
    TABLE testdb.ACCOMODATION
    (
        Id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        user_id BIGINT(30) NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        tel VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        mobile VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        fax VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        zip VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
        nation VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        region VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        province VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        municipality VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        stars ENUM('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE') NOT NULL,
        lat DECIMAL(10, 8), 
        lng DECIMAL(11, 8),

        CONSTRAINT fk_accomodation_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES testdb.USER (id),
        PRIMARY KEY (Id)
    )
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

When I perform this query into **DB Visualizer** (the IDE that I am using to interact with my DB) I obtain this error message:

```
11:26:01  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  Could not getColumn for MyMariaDB: Unknown system variable 'OPTION'
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE testdb.USER`

Answer (score 0):

Try set id UNSIGNEd instead of UNISGNED

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @AndreaNobili You have a typo in your query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok but this is not the real problem, I have removed the UNSIGNES reference in my query but I still have the same error